# Spring Boot WebSocket Server Can't Have Any Connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I am using unity websocket for client side and it works with Java but i want Spring Boot WebSocket Server but Unity can't connect the Server.

I just have 2 simple class:

Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

}
```

I removed SockJs because i've learn WebSocketSharp doesn't support the SockJS i guess

And my Controller:

```
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {

    @MessageMapping("/sendMessage")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public String sendMessage(String message) {
        return message;
    }

}
```

My unity connection url is :  ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8887/ws");

What should i do with those "topic/public" and "/sendMessage" paths i dont know what does it means ?

I just wanna see basic chat messages on spring boot console like core java.

Answer (score 0):

Let test postman,you subscribe destincation:/topic/public (create session) and send destination:/app/sendMessage (broker will sent to client that is subscribed to /topic/public)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).